# Action after .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a problem with this peace of code:

```
if(s.length > 0){
    jQuery("#ajax-load").html('<img src="/wp-content/themes/fearlessly/images/712.GIF" style="margin: 208px auto; width: 50px; height: 50px; display:block;" />');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/",
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            s: s,
            style: jQuery.trim(jQuery('.style').val()),
            key: jQuery.trim(jQuery('.key').val()),
            guitar: jQuery.trim(jQuery('.guitar').val()),
        },
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery("#ajax-load").html(jQuery(data));
            alert('');
            wrapDiv();
        },
    });
}
```

I want to invoke a "wrapDiv" after jQuery("#ajax-load").html(jQuery(data)); but nothing happens. I also tried to run alert message but it seems to be the same problem.

Comment: remove the `,` after `success: function()`

Comment: are you sure about the url??

Comment: Yes, .html() works perfect. Everything behind it is a mess.

Comment: Why you just put "/" in url part?

Comment: I am sending "s" parameter to main page which is responsible for searching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you do not need to use jQuery in success call back and you have extra comma(`,`) after success call back.

replace this:

```
 success: function(data) {
            jQuery("#ajax-load").html(jQuery(data));
            alert('');
            wrapDiv();
        },
```

by :

```
 success: function(data) {
            jQuery("#ajax-load").html(data);
            alert('');
            wrapDiv();
        },


error: function(xhr, error){
        alert(error);
 }
```

Comment: did you get alert inside success ?

Comment: @KrzysztofGrech make sure that you dont have any console errors. Also check the network tab.

Comment: i have added error call back. check if you got any alert from error call back @KrzysztofGrech

Comment: I don't have anything. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: then in your script ajax call is not executed.

Comment: If i delete `jQuery("#ajax-load").html(jQuery(data));` everything works just perfect. But obviously i don't see my content.